# Activityindicator not working with FFImageLoading

Tags: xamarin, activity-indicator, ffimageloading

The code works with the normal  but not with FFImageLoading. The ActivityIndicator is not displaying... What am I doing wrong?

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:PinchPanContainer>
            <local:PinchPanContainer.Content HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage RetryCount="5" RetryDelay="1" CacheDuration="1" x:Name="MyImage" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" DownsampleToViewSize="False"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>
            </local:PinchPanContainer.Content>
        </local:PinchPanContainer>
        <ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{x:Reference MyImage}" IsRunning="{Binding CachedImage.IsLoading}"  IsVisible="{Binding CachedImage.IsLoading}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding path you use is not correct, it should be `IsLoading` instead of `CachedImage.IsLoading`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101219155130/uncyclopedia/images/7/70/Facebooklogin.png" LoadingDelay="2000" RetryCount="5" RetryDelay="1" CacheDuration="1" x:Name="MyImage" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" DownsampleToViewSize="False"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    <ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{x:Reference MyImage}" Color="Red" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}"  IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Refer: [data-binding-basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics)